# How to remove attribute from tikz ER diagram?

Tags: latex, entity-relationship, tikz

I am working with a project on VMC, where I need to present the structure of the code. I tried to use an ER diagram, but I am not able to remove the last attribute from the entity. The code looks as following

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{er,positioning}
```

--

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=1.5cm]
  \node[entity] (node1) {VMC}
    %[grow=down,sibling distance=4cm]
    child {node[attribute] {Attribute 1}};
  \node[entity] (node2) [below right = of node1] {WF};
  \node[entity] (node3) [below left = of node1] {Main};
  \node[entity] (node4) [below right = of node3] {GD};
  \node[relationship] (rel1) [above = of node4, below = of node1] {Tools};

  \path (node1) edge node {} (node2)
                edge node {} (node3)
                edge node {} (rel1);
  \path (node4) edge node {} (node2)
                edge node {} (node3)
                edge node {} (rel1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and the diagram looks like this

[image]

It is kind of what I want, but I would like to remove the attribute box and move the Tools box up to the center. Hope someone can help me with this, I am new to tikz.

Comment: Could you post the code that defines `entity` and `relationship` too?

Comment: \usetikzlibrary{er,positioning}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the question, you only need to remove the corresponding `Attribute 1` code and add a distance from `rel1` to `node1`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=1.5cm]
  \node[entity] (node1) {VMC}
    %[grow=down,sibling distance=4cm]
    child {};
  \node[entity] (node2) [below right = of node1] {WF};
  \node[entity] (node3) [below left = of node1] {Main};
  \node[entity] (node4) [below right = of node3] {GD};
  \node[relationship] (rel1) [below=1cm of node1] {Tools};

  \path (node1) edge node {} (node2)
                edge node {} (node3)
                edge node {} (rel1);
  \path (node4) edge node {} (node2)
                edge node {} (node3)
                edge node {} (rel1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]